# Include NULLs in Join (already utilizing left join)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table @rpt_year_month that includes the latest 6 months in YYYYMM form in it and nothing else (there is other information but it is limited to rows with those 6 months; 6 total rows).  I am trying to join it with a table that has information segmented out by month, however some "materials" have no data for some of the months.  I have an example of what I want the pull to look like below for one specific material:

[Correct Material Pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFYfZ.jpg)

However, when I run it for anything other than joining on a specific material (as you will see in my code) it does not return any nulls.  Is there a way to replicate the results above so that every material will show in this fashion?  My code is below:

```
    With picard as (
Select c.client
,COALESCE(c.fiscal_year_month_key,r.cal_year_month) as cal_year_month
,c.material_nbr
,c.plant
,c.stock_qty
,c.stock_value from @rpt_year_month r

LEFT JOIN

@cmbnd_inv_period_qty c ON

r.cal_year_month = c.fiscal_year_month_key
AND material_nbr = '100000009428'
)
Select * into #worf from picard;

Select * from #worf
Drop Table #worf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate all the rows and then use a `left join`.  So, I think this is what you want:

```
Select c.client,
       coalesce(c.fiscal_year_month_key, r.cal_year_month) as cal_year_month,
       m.material_nbr, c.plant, c.stock_qty, c.stock_value
from (select distinct material_nbr from from @rpt_year_month r) m cross join
     @rpt_year_month r left join
     @cmbnd_inv_period_qty c 
     ON r.cal_year_month = c.fiscal_year_month_key ;
```

Comment: This helped me get to what I needed to do, although I ended up using some Temp Tables along with the Cross Join.  Thank you!